# Using libuuid / uuid-dev with C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm looking to use [`libuuid`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libuuid) with a C++11 program. However, I think I might be going about this incorrectly. According to `uuid.h`, the `uuid_t` is a unsigned char array of 16 items (expected). My approach to building a `std::string` with this was as follows:

```
uuid_t uuidObj;
uuid_generate(uuidObj);
std::string aString;

for (auto i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
   aString += uuidObj[i];
}
```

I know that this can't be the most approriate solution (while avoiding a `malloc` in C++11, yikes!), any tips from y'all?

Comment: maybe **construct** that poor string object? `std::string aString(std::begin(uuidObj), std::end(uuidObj));`

Comment: I didn't think that that would work. It being a native array, I wasn't aware that `std::begin` and `std::end` worked on things of that nature. I'll try it!

Comment: @jackalcine begin and end works perfectly fine on primitive arrays *while* they have not decayed into a pointer. A primitive array not being aware of its own length is a myth (or rather a result of poor/imprecise teaching).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can initialize the string within the constructor itself, passing the begin and end pointers as iterators.

```
uuid_t uuidObj;
uuid_generate(uuidObj);
std::string aString{ uuidObj, uuidObj + 16 };
```

*The Pragmatic Croissant* is also correct that you may free yourself of worrying about the array size by using the more C++11 idiomatic:

```
std::string aString{ std::begin(uuidObj), std::end(uuidObj) };
```

Also, your code in the question only copies the first 15 characters.

Comment: *headdesk* 4 years of this language and I'm still making silly mistakes like this. Thanks!

Comment: Drew, why not `std::begin()` and `std::end()`? that'd be more robust than hard coding magic numbers…

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I'm going to use `begin()` myself in lieu of it being more agnostic for whatever iteratable construct is available.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant old habits die hard.  :)

Comment: I updated it to cover all 16 @DrewDormann, got too used to `begin()` and `end()`!

Answer (score 1):

In uuid-dev 2.31.1, they provide a `uuid_unparse` function.

```
uuid_t uuidObj;
char str[100];
uuid_generate(uuidObj);
uuid_unparse(uuidObj, str);
std::string _uuid{str};
std::cout << _uuid << std::endl;
```